# AR - Google Scene Viewer - How did FCA do this?

Tags: google-chrome, augmented-reality, arcore

Recently I came across [FCA Website for CES 2021](https://fcaces2021.com) and at a point, when you click  on the first car you get a QR code. By flashing this QR code you are redirected [to this page](https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/web?enableColorPicker&file=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fsearch-ar-vehicles%2FJhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.glb&title=2021%20Jeep%20Wrangler%204XE&referrer=google.com%3AAUTOS%3Aces-c9&colorableMesh=Paint_Color_BD&card_content=https%3A%2F%2Fscene-viewer-preview.appspot.com%2Fscene-viewer%2Fweb%2Finfocard%3FenableColorPicker%26thumbnail%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FJhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.png%26file%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FJhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.glb%26title%3D2021%2BJeep%2BWrangler%2B4XE%26colorableMesh%3DPaint_Color_BD%26colorBaseUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252Fcolors%252F%26referrer%3Dgoogle.com%253AAUTOS%253Aces-c9%26carousel%3D%255B%257B%2522file%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FJhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.glb%2522%252C%2522title%2522%253A%25222021%252BJeep%252BWrangler%252B4XE%2522%252C%2522thumbnail%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FJhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.png%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522file%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FOK578yP7NrDgowmRIfYK4mu.glb%2522%252C%2522title%2522%253A%25222020%252BJeep%252BWrangler%2522%252C%2522thumbnail%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FOK578yP7NrDgowmRIfYK4mu.png%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522file%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FFuLIQjyCrEVWMh4qu3cgaRf.glb%2522%252C%2522title%2522%253A%25222020%252BJeep%252BCherokee%2522%252C%2522thumbnail%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FFuLIQjyCrEVWMh4qu3cgaRf.png%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522file%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FZsKQhfMNeiRD52Wu9cKKxqB.glb%2522%252C%2522title%2522%253A%25222020%252BJeep%252BCompass%2522%252C%2522thumbnail%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FZsKQhfMNeiRD52Wu9cKKxqB.png%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522file%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FMct7cEaDUJhpiIZ9bUuShQA.glb%2522%252C%2522title%2522%253A%25222020%252BJeep%252BRenegade%2522%252C%2522thumbnail%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fstorage.googleapis.com%252Fsearch-ar-vehicles%252FMct7cEaDUJhpiIZ9bUuShQA.png%2522%257D%255D&iosFile=https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.usdz&quicklookEnabled=true).

By decoding the URL and looking  at how it was made, I first thought it was  very easy to do. I removed some parts and tried to replace the models by one I did on Blender very easily.

Here is the decoded url:

```
https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/web?enableColorPicker&file=https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.glb&title=2021+Jeep+Wrangler+4XE&referrer=google.com:AUTOS:ces-c9&colorableMesh=Paint_Color_BD&card_content=https://scene-viewer-preview.appspot.com/scene-viewer/web/infocard?enableColorPicker&thumbnail=https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.png&file=https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.glb&title=2021+Jeep+Wrangler+4XE&colorableMesh=Paint_Color_BD&colorBaseUrl=https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/colors/&referrer=google.com:AUTOS:ces-c9&carousel=[{"file":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.glb","title":"2021+Jeep+Wrangler+4XE","thumbnail":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.png"},{"file":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/OK578yP7NrDgowmRIfYK4mu.glb","title":"2020+Jeep+Wrangler","thumbnail":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/OK578yP7NrDgowmRIfYK4mu.png"},{"file":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/FuLIQjyCrEVWMh4qu3cgaRf.glb","title":"2020+Jeep+Cherokee","thumbnail":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/FuLIQjyCrEVWMh4qu3cgaRf.png"},{"file":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/ZsKQhfMNeiRD52Wu9cKKxqB.glb","title":"2020+Jeep+Compass","thumbnail":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/ZsKQhfMNeiRD52Wu9cKKxqB.png"},{"file":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/Mct7cEaDUJhpiIZ9bUuShQA.glb","title":"2020+Jeep+Renegade","thumbnail":"https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/Mct7cEaDUJhpiIZ9bUuShQA.png"}]&iosFile=https://storage.googleapis.com/search-ar-vehicles/JhwKxj5FWvWq0XvZuDb4mZ7.usdz&quicklookEnabled=true
```

But by replacing the model, I get an access denied from Google. I  think it is due to the referrer parameter (here google.com:AUTOS:ces-c9) but then here I come to the actual question: How do you  get your  own  referrer? Did anyone try to do this recently? Is the access denied really due to the referrer?

Here is what I tried

```
https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/web?file=https://filebin.net/kvl7eh5cvmkjossg/test.glb?t=s42h134s&referrer=google.com:AUTOS:ces-c9&iosFile=https://filebin.net/kvl7eh5cvmkjossg/test.usdz?t=cxc71ics&quicklookEnabled=true
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you find out anything about this?